# How can I create on execution time the quantity of divs that I want depending on the SQL data?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application about virtual classrooms. I have a card to show every classroom that user was joined, this data was saved in my SQL database, and every classroom needs to be shown on a card created by HTML tags.

I have the card developed and I need to create the quantity of cards necessary based on the quantity of classrooms who the user was joined. I need to do some things like create cards (HTML) in the ASP.NET code, do each button present on each card does the same thing but depending on the classroom. I need the cards be created on execution time and I really don't know how can I do this.

If someone knows about, can help me please?

Sorry for my English I speak Spanish and I try not use the translator because it translates wrong, sometimes.

See the screenshot explaining what I'm trying to say:

[image: Example]

I tried to show some cards and fill with data but not easy to use for user, better is show the necessary cards no more nor less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much thank you, I found a better way for do it, now I'm using the `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl` for create html controls and `System.Web.UI.WebControls.xxxx` for create asp controls and on each tag I apply propierties with `xxx.Attributes.Add("class", "pcodigoca");`, text with                            `pcodigo.InnerText = "CÓDIGO DE CLASE:";` and child tags with `xxx.InnerHtml += "<span class=\"pidclas\">" + detalleclase[3].ToUpper() + "</span>";`, I applied this on the Load methods and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create one div with id in which you can add dynamic data cards. For the data you can call jQuery ajax call and send data in response once you get response from server do code as below.

Lets assume that you have one div with id "maindiv"

Now in the response section write

Var html = "";
$("#maindiv").append();

So inside childDiv you can add your html of cards and by dynamic counter you can manage unique id as well for all controlls

Comment: So much thank you, I found a better way for do it, now I'm using the `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl` for create html controls and `System.Web.UI.WebControls.xxxx` for create asp controls and on each tag I apply propierties with `xxx.Attributes.Add("class", "pcodigoca")`, text with                            `pcodigo.InnerText = "CÓDIGO DE CLASE:";` and child tags with `xxx.InnerHtml += "<span class=\"pidclas\">" + detalleclase[3].ToUpper() + "</span>"` and I ad them to the main div with `maindiv.Controls.Add(idclass)` , I applied this on the Load methods and it works perfectly.